# webview - origin is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin (convert angular to mobile using cordova)

Tags: android, angular, cordova, cors, alfresco

Im trying to create a angular app using Alfresco adf components (https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-ng2-components) and need to have a mobile app too, so i decide use cordova to generate apk.

I follow the following tutorial (https://medium.com/@nacojohn/convert-your-angular-project-to-mobile-app-using-cordova-f0384a7711a6) to generate my apk.

All seems to works fine, apk was generated and install in BlueStack, until i have to make login in my app.

[Origin is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fkPK.png)

I know that i need to have a whitelist policy for navigating the application webview

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>HelloWorld</name>
  <description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
  </description>
  <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
  </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
  <engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" />
  <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.4" />
</widget>
```

**index.html**

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"
```

My angular web app have a dev-server proxy to fix the CORS problem

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/alfresco": {
    "target": "server-url",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  },
  "/activiti-app": {
    "target": "another-server-url",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

I dont know what i need to do more. Have i made something wrong? need to do something more?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was lack of configuration in **app.config.json**.

Instead of

```
"ecmHost": "http://{hostname}{:port}",
"bpmHost": "http://{hostname}{:port}"
```

I just need to set ecmHost and bpmHost to my servers and all works fine.

Thanks for helping guys

Answer (score 3):

I think you should enable CORS in the Alfresco server, you can achieve that either by:

- Including this [dependency](https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/#nexus-search;quick~enablecors) in you Alfresco extension.
- Or by enabling CORS directly in the Tomcat server, full details can be found in the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter).

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable CORS for details see [Getting Started with Alfresco Application Development Framework](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6600-adf-101-getting-started-with-alfresco-application-development-framework)